# Does OpenCV UMat always reside on GPU?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencl, opencv3.0

I would like to know that whether OpenCV UMat always resides on GPU side if there is a OpenCL-compatible GPU available? Does "cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true)" make any difference?

If UMat does sits on GPU side, does it mean that the data transferring between CPU-GPU only happens when I call umat.getMat()?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No the `UMat` doesn't completely resides on a single hardware component like CPU or GPU, The `UMat` internally implements OpenCL framework which tries to harness the processing power of any capable hardware attached to the device, it could be CPU, GPU or even Digital Signal Processor present in mobile devices, so OpenCL performs efficient multi-processing along various available devices capable of processing. For more information follow this [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/)